# How to create a regex that matches CREATE BITMAP (...); DML in multiple files?

Tags: regex, grep

I have several DDL scripts that contains lines such as this:

```
CREATE TABLE (...) TABLESPACE MY_TABLESPACE;

CREATE INDEX MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_REGULAR_INDEX_1 
  ON MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN1) TABLESPACE MY_TABLESPACE;

CREATE BITMAP INDEX MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_BITMAP_INDEX_1
  ON MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN2) TABLESPACE MY_TABLESPACE;

CREATE INDEX MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_REGULAR_INDEX_2
  ON MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN3) TABLESPACE MY_TABLESPACE;
```

Since there are several scripts, I want to create a grep regex that would match whole DML commands that start with **CREATE BITMAP INDEX MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_BITMAP_INDEX_1 ON MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN) TABLESPACE MY_TABLESPACE;**, in order to create a single maintenance script.

Comment: Which parts should literally match vs which parts should generically match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab the commands which starts with `CREATE BITMAP` through grep,

```
$ grep -oPz 'CREATE BITMAP[\S\s]*?;$' file
CREATE BITMAP INDEX MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_BITMAP_INDEX_1
  ON MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN2) TABLESPACE MY_TABLESPACE;
```

From `man grep`

```
-Z, --null                print 0 byte after FILE name
-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
```

Comment: it works great on linux GNU's grep, but it doesn't work on mac's BSD grep, installing using macports

Comment: another issue is that it is printing the file names when I use a 
   `grep -oPz 'CREATE BITMAP[\S\s]*?;(?=$)' *`